# Can flight crew book tickets for themselves, on the same flight?

Tags: commercial-aviation, passenger, crew

Is it possible that flight crew book a ticket for themselves, for say utilizing their rest time better (like Emirates offers mid air shower to first class passengers, but not to crew)?

Comment: They could book it but why would you? The cost of a seat is almost certainly more than the pay for the flight so it would be a waste of money.

Comment: If the flight was full, every airline int he world would bump the flight crew to make space for an extra passenger. If the flight wasn't full the crew could go and sit in the spare seat if it was considered appropriate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Since the pilot won't check-in their *flight bag*, the booking will be cancelled (no-show).
2. They won't board with the passengers, so they won't be counted, same end result. Answer is **no**.
3. Many airlines now prohibit active duty (including relief) flight-crew from mingling with the passengers. Long gone are the days of the pilot walking up and down the plane.
4. That would be the most expensive shower in the history of showers. A first-class Emirates long haul flight is easily $24,000 (SFO-DXB).
5. [Crew rest areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew_rest_compartment) are beds for a reason, a shower goes against the idea of sleeping (may not be a universal thing though). But I wouldn't want to see my flight-crew in a robe going to bed after a nice warm shower. Unless the robe comes with epaulets.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure Emirates' crew doesn't make enough money to book First on their flights. However, if I'm wrong about that, please let me know, as I may need to consider changing careers. :)

Comment: Interesting demonstration: +1. However this would only be the most expensive shower in the history of *crew members*. I've always thought that being powerful is not booking at this price, it's flying the aircraft yourself if such is your royal desire.

Comment: What's the reason for prohibiting crew from mingling with passengers?

Comment: It may lead to inappropiate behaviour, less efficient(less time to serve others), safety etc,